# why does my ReWrite rule not rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the urls like

```
site.com/eng?sentence=a-sentence
```

to be like:

```
site.com/eng/a-sentence
```

I only want the text shown in the brower url to change, I dont want a redirect.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+eng?sentence=([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /eng/%1 [NC,L,NE]
```

I have fiddled with it, comparing other rewrite rules i found for a long time, but just cant get it to work, And i really can't figure out why. I tried removing all other rewrite from my htaccess everytime i tested.

here is my htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

Options -Indexes -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+eng?sentence=([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /eng/%1 [NC,L,NE]


<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

preferably, if you could fix my rule rather than write your own one that I won't likely understand, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only want the text shown in the browser url to change, I dont want a
>   redirect.

**To change URL in browser you need external redirect using `R` flag.**

Also `?` is special regex symbol and to match a literal `?` you need to escape it like `\?`. Also you would need a `?` in the target URI's end to strip off query string.

### Your complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# actual oneto pretty URL - external redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+eng\.php\?sentence=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /eng/%1? [L,NE,R=302]

# pretty URL to actual one - internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^eng/([^/]+)/?$ /eng.php?sentence=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

#### I highly recommend you to read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I would love to believe you but that rule gives me a 500 error. even when i remove all other rewrite rules from my htaccess.

Comment: Well that rule in isolation definitely works and redirects to `/localhost/eng/a-sentence`. But the onus is on you to cleanup your system and make sure there is no other .htaccess any where and there is no other rewrite rule. Reporting 500 is not enough, you need to read your apache error.log and find out the real error message.

Comment: Check edit now for complete .htaccess. Please stop creating new question and attend this one to final resolution.

Comment: this works and is what i need i think. The one left over problem i have which confused me before is that all the images that were declared relative to the current directory have all been redirected to site.com/eng/ along with the url redirect. is there some way i can set the working directory or should i just set absolute paths or move the files to site.com/eng/ directory?

Comment: Made another edit, try it now. But yes use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: i have started changing the paths, and it is fixing the last issues, i will just leave it at that, because im mighty tired of fiddling with this. thank you for your time!